# Store quiz score in account

Tags: php, sql

I have created a database where a user creates an account by entering their email address and password.

I also followed a tutorial where a user completes a quiz and their username and score is stored into a separate database. How can I store the score of the user to the email they registered with on the separate database? Because currently the user account is created at the start of the process and the user account for the quiz are not connected.

Comment: Would you mind showing us your current code?

Comment: in order to connect data from different tables, you need to have an external key. use the e-mail address or the id of the user. you might need to add the e-mail to the score table.

Answer (score 0):

Before starting the quiz, you must have created a login page where the user provides the loginid(email) and password.
You can start a php session using that information. Set the session variable to the email id and password. 
And when the user logs out after finishing the quiz, before destroying the session, you can set the score in your database using the session variable.